# Circle around the cross

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Hey there is a circle around the cross of my cursor how do I remove it[image]

Comment: You're using the 'circle select tool'. You can cycle through the other select tools with 'W' on your keyboard, or by clicking and holding on the active toolbar item on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You've accidentally changed your selection mode.

[image]

The hotkey for this is <kbd>W</kbd>.